# Php custom function is Truncating Text but i don't want it to

Tags: php

I am passing a large amount of text to a PHP function and having it return it compressed. The text is being cut off. Not all of it is being passed back out.  Like some of the words at the very end aren't showing up after being compressed. Does PHP limit this somewhere?

```
 function compress($buffer) {
    /* remove comments */
    $buffer = preg_replace('!/\*[^*]*\*+([^/][^*]*\*+)*/!', '', $buffer);
    /* remove tabs, spaces, newlines, etc. */
    $buffer = str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r", "\n", "\t", '  ', '    ', '    '), '', $buffer);
    return $buffer;
}
```

Is the function. Its from http://www.antedes.com/blog/webdevelopment/three-ways-to-compress-css-files-using-php

Is there like a setting in php.ini to fix this?

Comment: it is quite possible that there is some problem with the css file that you are parsing... did the css file worked fine when uncompressed.. and how are you getting the `$buffer` variable?? are you doing a fopen?

Comment: The file worked fine before. Its a .js file. Made the header('Content-type: text/javascript'); be javascript and not css. Got some very large Js files since alot of my site is Ajax.

Answer (score 1):

Your `compress()` function looks decent for CSS files, not JS. This is what I use to "compress" CSS (including jquery-ui and other monsters):

```
function compress_css($string)
{
    $string = preg_replace('~/\*[^*]*\*+([^/][^*]*\*+)*/~', '', $string);
    $string = preg_replace('~\s+~', ' ', $string);
    $string = preg_replace('~ *+([{}+>:;,]) *~', '$1', trim($string));
    $string = str_replace(';}', '}', $string);
    $string = preg_replace('~[^{}]++\{\}~', '', $string);
    return $string;
}
```

and for JavaScript files this one: https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2 (or this: http://lisperator.net/uglifyjs/#demo)

I'm sure there are other good tools for the same tasks, just find what suits you and use that.